# How to wait for keyboard input in Qt (c++)

Tags: c++, qt

When I push a button I want it to:

-change my label,

-wait for fixed time OR for any key pressed by user (let's say SPACE)

-then change label again.

---

For now I have this:

```
void MainWindow::on_PushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->labeltext->setText("bla");

    SLEEP(3000);

    ui->labeltext->setText("blabla");
}
```

where my SLEEP function:

```
void SLEEP(int ms){
  QEventLoop loop;
  QTimer::singleShot(ms, &loop, SLOT(quit()) );
  loop.exec();
};
```

is working OK.

How to implement waiting for key?

---

As  Thomas Matthews suggested i tried to use timer, but i'm stuck with creating it.
I add`QTimer timer1` to header and in source`timer1.setSingleShot(1)` while creating mainwindow and in my button slot:

```
timer1.start(5000);
connect(timer1, SIGNAL(timeout()), ui->labeltext, SLOT(setText("blabla")));
```

but I get error

```
C2664: 'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const QObject *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'QTimer' to 'const QObject *'
```

Also using timer straight in button slot:

```
QTimer *timer2 = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer2, SIGNAL(timeout()),ui->labeltext,SLOT(setText("blabla")));
timer2->setSingleShot(1);
timer2->start(2000);
```

has no efects (it compiles at least but is not changing label).

What should I do?

Comment: You really don't want to do that.  QT is event driven.  You will want to use a Timer object and give it a function that changes the text of your label.  The timer will expire then call your function.  In your message receiver, when a key press message is received, disable the timer object.

Comment: 1) Use customized `QPushButton` and corresponting signals, instead of `QLabel`. 2) Install event filter on your label which will catch keyboard events. And don't forget to use `StrongFocus` on label.

Answer (score 0):

To give this a shot, the code below seems to do what you want if I understand the question correctly.

```
#ifndef MYDIALOG_H
#define MYDIALOG_H

#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QKeyEvent>

class Dialog: public QDialog, private Ui::Dialog
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
  Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0) : QDialog(parent), timer_(0) {
    setupUi(this);
    pushButton->installEventFilter(this);
  }

  virtual bool eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event)
  {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
      QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
      if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Space && label->text() == "Hello" ) {
        setText();
        timer_->stop();
        return false;
      }
    }
    return QDialog::eventFilter(target, event);

  }

public slots:

  void on_pushButton_clicked() {
    if( label->text() != "Initial Text Here!" ) {
      return;
    }
    label->setText("Hello");
    if( !timer_ ) timer_ = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer_,SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(setText()) );
    timer_->start(3000);
  }

  void setText() {
    label->setText("Bye!");
  }

protected:
  virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * e) {
    if( e->key() == Qt::Key_Space ) {
      setText();
      timer_->stop();
    }
  }

private:
  QTimer *timer_;

};

#endif
```

Some explanations: 
I created a very simple dialog with just a `QLabel` and a `QPushButton`. I set the initial text of the `QLabel` to

> Initial Text Here!

The method `on_pushButton_clicked()` will be invoked when you click the button. The method then

- changes the text of the label
- instantiates the `QTimer` member (could also be done in constructor or probably even initialization list)
- connects the timeout event of the timer to the `setText()` method and launches the timer with a three second delay.

Note that in the code you posted you used a `QTimer` not a pointer, but the `connect` method expects a pointer, so you either have to change your `timer1` to a pointer, or pass it as `&timer1` to `connect`.

In order to get the key press, there are two things:

First you reimplement the `keyPressEvent` method to call the `setText()` method if the key happens to be the space bar ( `Qt::Key_Space` ). In addition, it can happen that the key press event is received by the `pushButton` and not the dialog. For that you can install an EventFilter on the `QPushButton` which will make sure that events passed the `QPushButton` are intercepted so that you execute an action different from the standard, or in all other cases you just pass on the event.

The code is obviously not very optimized or very pretty but simply tries to illustrate things.

Let me know if this helps